# Liquid filter collection where not null

Tags: jekyll, liquid, yaml-front-matter

In my front matter for *some* pages (not all) I have:

```
---
top-navigation:
    order: 2
---
```

Using liquid I want to filter all site pages which have a `top-navigation` object and sort by `top-navigation.order`.

I'm trying `sort:'top-navigation.order'` but that's throwing an exception of `undefined method [] for nil:NilClass`. I tried `where:"top-navigation", true` but it's not equating truthy values.

How can I filter for pages that have `top-navigation` and then sort?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two steps:

1. Create an array with pages that contains the `top-navigation` key.

   We create an empty array and then push the items that have the key.

   ```
   {% assign navposts = ''|split:''%}
   {% for post in site.posts %}
   {% if post.top-navigation %}
   {% assign navposts = navposts|push:post%}
   {% endif %}
   {% endfor %}
   ```
2. Sort the above array by `top-navigation.order`

   ```
   {% assign navposts = navposts|sort: "top-navigation.order"%}
   ```

Printing results:

```
{% for post in navposts %}
<br>{{ post.title }} - {{post.top-navigation}}
{% endfor %}
```

For pages use `site.pages`.

Comment: this works very well. I even added a uniq filter on it for my tag list.

Comment: ended up here after reading the jekyll filter list. There's a "where: nil" filter , available starting from v4.0.0 ([docs](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/liquid/filters/#detecting-nil-values-with-where-filter400)). Wasn't sure how to get the converse filter. This answer seems more portable anyway.

Answer (score 5):

In Jekyll 3.2.0+ (and Github Pages) you can use the where_exp filter like so:

```
{% assign posts_with_nav = site.posts | where_exp: "post", "post.top-navigation" %}
```

Here, for each item in site.posts, we bind it to the 'post' variable and then evaluate the expression 'post.top-navigation'. If it evaluates truthy, then it will be selected.

Then, putting it together with the sorting, you'd have this:

```
{%
  assign sorted_posts_with_nav = site.posts 
  | where_exp: "post", "post.top-navigation" 
  | sort: "top-navigation.order"
%}
```

---

Liquid also has the `where` filter which, when you don't give it a target value, selects all elements with a truthy value for that property:

```
{% assign posts_with_nav = site.posts | where: "top-navigation" %}
```

Unfortunately, this variant does not work with Jekyll.